# Can't run downloaded files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

So I have this problem with IntelliJ every time I run a Java file from a .zip file. Every time I open a .zip file and try to run the Java file in IntelliJ, I can't actually run the code within the file. It opens, and there is no error in the code itself, but I'm literally unable to click the button that let's me compile and run the code.

This isn't an issue when I create the Java file from scratch. However, if I download a .zip file, or if I zip the folder with my Java file in it, I am presented with this same issue. Can anyone help me? This has made working with this IDE a living hell, and I'm not allowed to switch out from it.

I understand this probably is a poor explanation. If there's anything else I can provide, please let me know and I will be more than happy to oblige.

This is a "picture" of the problem. The file extension should be `class`, not `java`. And the play button on the right should be green.
[image]

Comment: Extract that zip file to any folder and then `File->New->Project from Existing Sources`

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/

Answer (score 4):

No IDE in the world can compensate non-understanding. IntelliJ is still the best Java IDE that is available and will hardly ever be beaten.

Why do you think the extension should be `class`? A `class` file is not Java sources, but compiled Java file. IntelliJ can automatically decompile a `class` file to some extent to show you something that is similar to the original `java` file, but the source file always is a `java` file. If you compile a `java` file, you get a `class` file out of it.

Regarding the greyed out "Play" button. Left of it you see a dropdown that has nothing selected. This is a dropdown where you can select the current Run / Debug configuration, that you then can Run / Debug / Profile with the buttons to the right. If no run configuration is selected, those buttons of course are grayed out. Open the dropdown, create or select a run configuration and the buttons become active.

**If** the class you are looking at actually is a runnable class (has a `public static void main(String... args)` or `public static void main(String[] args)` method, then you will have a run button in the gutter on the left of the line containing `class Executor` and also in the gutter on the left of the line containing the main method. You can just click that run button and IntelliJ automatically generates a temporary run configuration for you, compiles the code and runs the run configuration for you.

If the class is *not* a runnable class, you cannot run it, neither with the gutter indicators, nor by creating a run configuration manually, because as the name suggests, only runnable classes are runnable.

Whether you can run a class or not has absolutely nothing to do with whether you zipped the class or not.

Comment: "No IDE in the world can compensate non-understanding. IntelliJ is still the best Java IDE that is available and will hardly ever be beaten." - yes.